# [the-elder-scrolls] vs [elder-scrolls]

Tags: support, tags

Shall we include articles or not?

1x https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls

5x https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls

Comment: This would be a good candidate for the new tag synonyms system that just rolled out on the trilogy.

Comment: @Corey: Can you provide a link or explain how it works? I filed a [retag-request](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/525/retagging-elder-scrolls-into-the-elder-scrolls), please feel free to answer there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand The Elder Scrolls game tags to include \[the-elder-scrolls\] prefix](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/expand-the-elder-scrolls-game-tags-to-include-the-elder-scrolls-prefix) (a more recent community consensus on the same topic)

Comment: @galacticninja I was asking about prefixing the "the" back then, not TES to each and every gametag

Comment: @Zommuter IMO, the more recent community consensus covers how to name all Elder Scrolls series-related tags (which includes prefixing "the").

Comment: @galacticninja Sure, but that's still a different thing. But no worries, I don't care either way since this one has long since been taken care of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't the series normally referred to as "The Elder Scrolls"? [Fan sites](http://tesnexus.com) seem to anyway.

Comment: exactly, and my first guess for a tag was typing "the-elder..." so that elder-scrolls wouldn't be suggested. That may happen to others

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as `elder-scrolls` has considerably more questions, I say we keep it on that. `the-elder-scrolls` seems overly descriptive, tags should be concise. It would be difficult to keep the articles on for very big names.