# Retagging [elder-scrolls] into [the-elder-scrolls] (Completed)

Tags: support, retag-request

As hinted in [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/480/the-elder-scrolls-vs-elder-scrolls/484#484) the series "The elder scrolls" is usually referred to by including the article, so I suggest retagging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand The Elder Scrolls game tags to include \[the-elder-scrolls\] prefix](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/expand-the-elder-scrolls-game-tags-to-include-the-elder-scrolls-prefix) (a more recent community consensus on the same topic)

Comment: @galacticninja I was asking about prefixing the "the" back then, not TES to each and every gametag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the re-tagging manually.

Comment: thanks. Can you also introduce a [synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479/allowing-users-with-a-nominal-amount-of-rep-to-submit-possible-tag-synonyms-and-v)?