# Is it possible to change [elder-scrolls-blades] to [the-elder-scrolls-blades]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Is it possible to change [elder-scrolls-blades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls-blades) to [the-elder-scrolls-blades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-blades)? This was discussed in the distant past and completed as per these two questions.
[Question1](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/480/the-elder-scrolls-vs-elder-scrolls), [Question 2](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/retagging-elder-scrolls-into-the-elder-scrolls-completed)

It is breaking my watched tags [the-elder-scrolls*]

I do not know how to go about doing this and hence this meta question.

Comment: Posting tag rename requests in meta is viable method for getting the job done. Now we just wait for a mod to see it and handle it accordingly :)

Comment: Yeah it's an unfortunate issue with the tag synonym system. Always happy to help out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done!**

- [elder-scrolls-blades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls-blades) → [the-elder-scrolls-blades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-blades)

```
updating post history, 10 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 10 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'the-elder-scrolls-blades' doesn't exist, renaming to 'elder-scrolls-blades'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [the-elder-scrolls-blades] and [elder-scrolls-blades] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym elder-scrolls-blades -> the-elder-scrolls-blades was approved!
```